# Heroku deploy with django database issue

Tags: django, database, heroku

I just deployed my app into heroku, everything seems to work just fine, but the problem is that I can't access the database from the APP, admin looks empty.

But the database is there on heroku when I check it:

[database in heroku](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xV9bu.png)

Settings.py

[Whitenoise](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SUEr9.png)
[whitenoise 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CG4eH.png)

[database conection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1LCUB.png)

[static](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0D41R.png)

urls.py

[static in URL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EQRWl.png)

I think maybe some config with the connection is missing, but I don't know what else I can do.

Comment: Please include code and data as text in the question, not by linking to images.

Answer (score 0):

Your local database is different than your production database. You have to make migrations, create a superuser, and repopulate your production database.

From Heroku cli:

`heroku run python manage.py migrate`

`heroku run python manage.py createsuperuser`

Comment: thanks for the answer! i solved with dump and loaddata manually, for some reason still unknow to me database was not populate corrrectly